# Inspector palette and Identity button in xcode 4.4.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am very new to the xcode. I'm trying to create my first GUI using xcode 4.4.1 following the steps describing in "Become an Xcoder" tutorial. But I can't find Inspector palette and Identity button in xcode 4.4.1 to specify class properies (in other words I can't find "Foo Identity" palette). Where it is located? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing command option 0
That will display the right side inspector.
It has several tabs that you will use frequently. 
The identity inspector is in there.

Xcode 4 is very much designed with keyboard shortcut usage in mind. 
Refer to the help menu and menu items frequently, practice the keyboard shortcuts. There is a LOT in Xcode 4, and it does take time to get familiar with it. Don't feel bad. Many long time users were slow to move to version 4 because it is so different from previous incarnations and the learning curve is steep at first.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how old the document version is you're using, but your looking for what is now called the "utilities area". Here's Apples [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheUtilityArea/AbouttheUtilityArea.html).